# How does the vote to close system work?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

For stackoverflow and it's related sites, how does the system for closing questions work?

Answer (score 3):

Each site has a variety of closing reasons, the standards being Exact Duplicate, Subjective & Arguemntative, Blatantly Offensive, and Spam. It takes 5 close votes to close a topic. Only those with over 3,000 rep can vote to close. If a moderator votes to close, it closes automatically. It takes 5 votes to reopen a question. You may not vote twice (only once for close and once for reopen).

Answer (score 1):

Questions can be closed for the following reasons:

- exact duplicate
- not programming related
- subjective and argumentative
- not a real question
- blatantly offensive
- no longer relevant
- too localized
- belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
- belongs on serverfault.com
- belongs on superuser.com
- spam

Comment: This is inaccurate due to the fact that different sites have different close reasons.

Comment: I still maintain the list should contain "belongs on refactormycode.com". :-)

Comment: @TheTXI: the question was about Stackoverflow specifically, no?

Comment: @fretje: Yes, but the closing mechanism can be described in terms that are used on every site. The only differences are the close reasons.